# FFMPEG concat filter, matches no streams

Tags: ffmpeg

Here is my command

```
ffmpeg -i 'Five.mov' -i 'top5.mov' -i 'Four.mov' -i 'top4.mov' -i 'Three.mov' \
       -i 'top3.mov' -i 'Two.mov' -i 'top2.mov' -i 'One.mov' -i 'top1.mov' anullsrc \
       -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] [3:v] [3:a] [4:v] [4:a] [5:v] [5:a] [6:v] [6:a] [7:v] [7:a] [8:v] [8:a] [9:v] [9:a] concat=n=10:v=1:a=1 [vv] [aa]" \
       -map "[vv]" -map "[aa]" 'top5final.mov'
```

`Five.mov` `Four.mov` `Three.mov` `Two.mov` `One.mov` don't have any audio, just video.  The rest of the videos have audio.

This is the error returned **Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] [3:v] [3:a] [4:v] [4:a] [5:v] [5:a] [6:v] [6:a] [7:v] [7:a] [8:v] [8:a] [9:v] [9:a] concat=n=10:v=1:a=1 [vv] [aa] matches no streams.**

How do i solve?

Answer (score 0):

`concat` filter needs to have an audio stream to be shorter than the corresponding video filter, and I suspect your spurious `anullsrc` argument was meant to serve as the missing audio streams... Instead, you need to define an input filter for the missing audio streams, and feed it multiple times to the `concat` filter as the audio stream of the files w/out audio:

```
ffmpeg -i 'Five.mov' -i 'top5.mov' -i 'Four.mov' -i 'top4.mov' -i 'Three.mov' \
       -i 'top3.mov' -i 'Two.mov' -i 'top2.mov' -i 'One.mov' -i 'top1.mov' \
       -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:n=1:c=channel_layout:s=sample_rate,aformat=sample_fmt \
       -filter_complex "[0:v][10:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][10:a][3:v][3:a][4:v][10:a] \
                        [5:v][5:a][6:v][10:a][7:v][7:a][8:v][10:a][9:v][9:a] \
                        concat=n=10:v=1:a=1[vv][aa]" \
       -map [vv] -map [aa] 'top5final.mov'
```

Not that matching stream property requirement applies to all streams. So, if the properties of the existing streams aren't identical, you need to precondition them with appropriate filters (i.e., `format` for video pixel format, `scale` for video frame size, `aformat` for audio sample format, channel layout, and sampling rate, and optionally `fps` for video frame rate.)

See [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat)

[edited to incorporate @Gyan's comment]

Comment: One `-f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc`  with no filter options will suffice. An `-i` input can be referenced multiple times in a filtergraph. The concat filter will auto convert if the audio props don't match.

Comment: @Gyan - Thanks for the tip. I was wondering about that but wasn't 100%. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Any reason why you removed the `[0]fps=24[fps0]` things? My inputs don't all have the same FPS. You also remove the setpts. I guess you removed the `:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2` because it was only relevant to a xstack filter?

Comment: Have you tried that command? I still have a `Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description matches no streams.`

Comment: @jokoon - Did you mean to comment on your answer? Anyway, yeah, add `fps` filters next to the `scale` filters. `:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2` removal = because that should be the default behavior you can leave it in

Comment: I don't see `:a` stream specifiers anywhere in yours or my commands.