# I have a ffmpeg command to concatenate 300+ videos of different formats. What is the proper syntax for the concat complex filter?

Tags: python, powershell, video, ffmpeg

I plan to concatenate a large amount of video files of different formats and resolution, some without sound, and add a short black screen "pause" of about 0.5s between each.

I wrote a python script to generate such command.

I created a 0.5s video file using `ffmpeg.exe -t 0.5 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x480 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p blank500ms.mp4`.

I then added a silent audio to it with `-f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest`

I now have the problem of adding a blank audio track for streams without one, but I don't want to generate new file, I want to add it to my complex filter.

This is my complex script and generate command.

The command (there are line returns, because I send this with the python subprocess module)

```
ffmpeg.exe
-i
input0.mp4
-i
input1.mp4
-i
input2.mp4
-i
input3.mp4
-i
input4.mp4
-i
input5.mp4
-i
input6.mp4
-i
input7.mp4
-i
input8.mp4
-i
input9.mp4
-i
input10.mp4
-f
lavfi
-i
anullsrc
-filter_complex_script
C:/filter_complex_script.txt
-map
"[final_video]"
-map
"[final_audio]"
output.mp4
```

The complex_filter_script:

```
[0]fps=24[fps0];
[fps0]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled0];
[1]fps=24[fps1];
[fps1]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled1];
[2]fps=24[fps2];
[fps2]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled2];
[3]fps=24[fps3];
[fps3]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled3];
[4]fps=24[fps4];
[fps4]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled4];
[5]fps=24[fps5];
[fps5]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled5];
[6]fps=24[fps6];
[fps6]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled6];
[7]fps=24[fps7];
[fps7]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled7];
[8]fps=24[fps8];
[fps8]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled8];
[9]fps=24[fps9];
[fps9]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled9];
[10]fps=24[fps10];
[fps10]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rescaled10];
[10]split=10[blank0][blank1][blank2][blank3][blank4][blank5][blank6][blank7][blank8][blank9];
[rescaled0:v][0:a][blank0][rescaled1:v][1:a][blank1][rescaled2:v][2:a][blank2][rescaled3:v][3:a][blank3][rescaled4:v][4:a][blank4][rescaled5:v][5:a][blank5][rescaled6:v][11:a][blank6][rescaled7:v][11:a][blank7][rescaled8:v][11:a][blank8][rescaled9:v][11:a][blank9]concat=n=22:v=1:a=1[final_video][final_audio]
```

As you can see, some video use `[11:a]`, because it's a silent audio stream.

input10.mp4, mapped to [10] and then split (or "cloned") into blanked0 to 9, is a short pause separator.

ffmpeg tells me the error

```
[Parsed_split_55 @ 000001591c33b280] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_split_55' filter output pad 1 (video) and the 'Parsed_concat_56' filter input pad 5 (audio)
[AVFilterGraph @ 000001591bf1e6c0] Cannot create the link split:1 -> concat:5
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

I'm a bit lost when it comes to using the [X:Y:Z] syntax, and how the order matter in the concat argument list.

I'm open to any other suggestion to solve my problem. I would rather do this in a single command, without intermediate file.

EDIT:

For details, I already wrote a large concat+xstack filter that worked well with 8GB of memory.

In this case, there are a lot of inputs, but those inputs are small, most of them are between 1 and 10MB, so it would probably not generate out-of-memory problems, although I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While theoretically doable, I don't recommend calling FFmpeg with so many input files. This will increase the memory footprint of the runtime and likely to bog down the speed (if not throwing an out-of-memory error). Instead, my suggestion is to approach this in 2 steps:

- Step 1: Transcode each video files so each is properly encoded exactly in the way you like it. Do this in a loop and save as intermediate files.
- Step 2: Copy-concat all the intermediate files to form the final output

The important part here is that all temp files have the exact same stream config. Video: codec, framerate (`fps`), pix_fmt (`pfmt`), size (`w`,`h`), and timebase and Audio: codec, sample_fmt (`sfmt`), sampling rate (`fs`), channel layout ('layout') and timebase. (I'm using these "variables" in the command sketches below inside curly braces.)

**Step 1 command sketches:**

Below I assuming that video & audio configs are identical among the input files except for the size, which you already addressed in your code. If not, you may need additional filters.

1. If video file has both audio & video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s={w}x{h}:d=0.5:r={fps},format={pfmt} \
       -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:n=1:c={layout}:s={fs},aformat={sfmt} \
       -filter_complex [0:v]scale={w}:{h}:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad={w}:{h}:-1:-1,setsar=1[v]; \
                       [v][0:a][1:v][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vout][aout] \
       -map [vout] -map [aout] -enc_time_base 0 output.mp4
```

2. If video file only has video stream:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s={w}x{h}:d=0.5:r={fps},format={pfmt} \
       -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:n=1:c={layout}:s={fs},aformat={sfmt} \
       -filter_complex [0:v]scale={w}:{h}:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad={w}:{h}:-1:-1,setsar=1[v]; \
                       [v][2:a][1:v][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vout][aout] \
       -map [vout] -map [aout] -enc_time_base 0 output.mp4
```

Note that the only difference between 1 & 2 is the 2nd input of `concat` filter. If audio is missing, just use the `aevalsrc` for the missing stream.

3. No 0.5-s padding for the last input video:

With audio

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -vf scale={w}:{h}:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad={w}:{h}:-1:-1,setsar=1 \
       -enc_time_base 0 output.mp4
```

Without audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:n=1:c={layout}:s={fs},aformat={sfmt} \
       -filter_complex [0:v]scale={w}:{h}:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad={w}:{h}:-1:-1,setsar=1[v]; \
                       [v][2:a]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[vout][aout] \
       -map [vout] -map [aout] -enc_time_base 0 output.mp4
```

3. Use `ffprobe` to identify whether the file has audio stream (you can also use ffmpeg, but I prefer this approach):

```
ffprobe -of default=nk=1:nw=1 -select_streams a -show_entries stream input.mp4
```

In python, you can run this command with `subprocess.run` with `stdout=sp.PIPE` and check the length of the obtained `stdout` bytes (>0 with audio, =0 no audio).

4. While running the per-input ffmpeg, also compose `ffconcat` text file.

[The `concat` demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) takes a text file as the input, and it has the following format:

```
ffconcat version 1.0

file output1.mp4
file output2.mp4
...
```

where the `output#.mp4` are the names of the files you generated in the loop. Build this file in the Step-1 loop and save it in the same directory as the intermediate video files (call it `ffconcat.txt`).

**Step 2 command sketch**

Most of the work is done at this point, and you should be able to obtain the final video by:

```
ffmpeg -i ffconcat.txt -c copy final.mp4
```

Warning: I didn't test these codes, so if you encounter any typo that you cannot figure out please leave a comment and I'll be happy to correct/clarify.

**One-n-done sketch**

What's written above can be extended to a single-run (or a partial combo) approach. Assume there are 100 files, then you can do:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 ... -i input99.mp4 \
       -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s={w}x{h}:d=0.5:r={fps},format={pfmt} \
       -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:n=1:c={layout}:s={fs},aformat={sfmt} \
       -filter_complex \ 
         [0:v]scale={w}:{h}:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad={w}:{h}:-1:-1,setsar=1[v0]; \
         [1:v]scale={w}:{h}:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad={w}:{h}:-1:-1,setsar=1[v1]; \
         ...
         [99:v]scale={w}:{h}:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad={w}:{h}:-1:-1,setsar=1[v99]; \
         [v0][0:a][100:v][101:a][v2][101:a][100:v][101:a]...[100:v][101:a][v99][99:a]concat=n=199:v=1:a=1[vout][aout] \
       -map [vout] -map [aout] output.mp4
```

Here, I assumed that the 1st and last have audio and the second has no audio. Input #100 = `color` filter, Input #101 = `aevalsrc` filter. The total number of video-audio stream pairs to concatenate is 199 (100 videos and 99 0.5-s pause. The key here is that you can reuse the filter outputs as many times as you need.

Comment: To avoid OOM, I could still try to do in batches of 50 files, and concatenate them after. Those inputs files are rather small and short, none are above 20MB, most are about 1 to 5MB.

Comment: Edited to include how to do all-in-one

Comment: I've read that I cannot reuse input more than once, shouldn't I use the split filter to clone an input? I will try during the week, thanks for the edit.

Comment: You're thinking of filter pads rather than input streams. [Gyan actually corrected me on this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71836658/4516027)

Comment: Sorry @kesh , I commented in the wrong question. In your last command, there are [0:a] and [100:a] filter pads, I think that's what I meant by `Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description matches no streams. `

Comment: Likely it means the input file does not have audio, so you need to use the `aevalsrc` stream instead. (`[100:a]` should be the one, so hopefully that isn't the one causing an issue.

Comment: I have checked and the stream does have audio... here is the full command https://bpa.st/4N6A and the complex script https://bpa.st/4QCA

Comment: FYI, you can chain 3 video filters (no need for `[fps]` label): `[0:v]fps=...,scale=...,,setsar=...[rescaled0]`

Comment: Everything looks ok. Post the full ffmpeg log.

Comment: https://bpa.st/LEPQ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244243/discussion-between-jokoon-and-kesh).

Comment: You got the 2 lavfi inputs backwards: [11:v][10:a] should read [10:v][11:a]

Comment: Got a lot of `cur_dts is invalid` (I expanded in the chat thing)